# CMake + VSCode: configure_file and linting

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

This may already have been asked and answered, but I couldn't find it if so.

I have VSCode and CMake setup and working fine and I am also using the ms-vscode.cmake-tools extension, and my c_cpp_properties.json has `"configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"`.

As part of my project CMakeLists.txt file I have:

```
configure_file(app_version.hpp.in app_version.hpp)
```

Obviously the actaul app_version.hpp file does not exist until cmake is run on the project and even then the actual file is placed into the build directory. The result of this is that the linter cannot find the file and so lots of red squiggles appear.

Is there a nice way to deal with this to make the linter happy, or do I have to specify a *"fake"* app_version.hpp with blank #defines etc?

Comment: In other IDEs you configure and generate before opening the project in the IDE or you have the IDE support for CMake to do that for you.

Comment: Do you have a compiler kit chosen?  The cmake-tools won't configure until you do.  You shouldn't need to manually change c_cpp_properties.json the cmake-tools and c/c++ extension play nicely together more or less automagically

Answer (score 0):

You can tell CMake where to put the result of `configure_file()`, even back into your source tree. You'll still have to run `cmake` first. As an example...

```
configure_file(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/templates/app_version.hpp.in ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/app_version.hpp)
```

I can't think of a project that I work on that *doesn't* write back like this to the source directory, so running `cmake` at least once after checkout is second nature to me. Remember to set up your version control to ignore the output file, otherwise you get a different kind of "red squiggly line".